# given information about primes dividing gcd and lcm, find # of prime factors dividing one of the numbers

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(a,b)$ is divisible by exactly $7$ distinct primes and $\mathop{\text{lcm}}[a,b]$ is divisible by exactly $28$ distinct primes.

If $a$ has fewer distinct prime factors than $b$, then $a$ has at most how many distinct prime factors?

I thought that it would be 28, but that does not work. I do not even know were to start. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: The question in the header doesn't appear to match the question in the body. Please clarify.

Comment: Whatever question you mean, I imagine that the extreme case would look like $a=\prod_{i=1}^7p_i$ and $b=\prod_{i=1}^{28}p_i$ where $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime.

Comment: I have fixed it, and I hope that it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a prime divides $\gcd(a,b)$, then it divides both $a$ and $b$. There are $7$ of these primes. However, if it divides $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ but **not** $\gcd(a,b)$, it must divide one of $a$ and $b$, but not both. How many such primes are there, and what ways are there to split them between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

a and b have 7 primes in common because of gcd. The remaining 21 (=28-7)primes are distributed between a and b. a gets 10 and b gets 11 at most since a has fewer primes. Hence totally a has at most 7+10=17 primes.